# Oracle SQL replace Character

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a Column in which I would like to replace a certain character, the problem is this character can be in the middle of the string or at the end. And I only want to replace this character and not all the other ones.

For example

```
Root#root#abc#test#stest#s#beta#402
Root#root#abc#test#stest#s
```

Now I want to replace the s with an uppercase S but only the s after the 5.#:

```
Root#root#abc#test#stest#S#beta#402
Root#root#abc#test#stest#S
```

The structure of the column is always like this, the character to replace is always after the 5th #. Replace wont work bc if I search for #s then the #stest would get #Stest.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed character to replace ( 's' in your example) you can use this:

```
with test(string) as ( select 'Root#root#abc#test#stest#s#beta#402' from dual)
select regexp_replace(string, '(.*)#(.*)#(.*)#(.*)#(.*)#s', '\1#\2#\3#\4#\5#S')
from test
```

This cuts the string in 5 blocks with and ending '#' and then replaces the 's' after the 5th block with its 'S'.

You can even use regexp to count the occurrences for you:

```
select regexp_replace(string, '(([^#]*#){5,5})s', '\1S')
from test
```

This counts exactly 5 occurrences of the block, without need to write it 5 times.

With a different approach, without regexp, you can try:

```
select substr(string, 1, instr(string, '#', 1, 5) ) ||
       upper(substr(string, instr(string, '#', 1, 5)+1, 1)) ||
       substr(string, instr(string, '#', 1, 5) + 2)
from test
```

This simply cuts the string in 3 parts (from the begigging to the 5th '#', the following character, the remaining part) and does `upper` of the character.
This can handle different characters, with no need to hardcode 's'

Comment: Thx for your answer, the regexp version was what I was looking for.